# Angular Custom Attribute Directive doesn't work right

Tags: angular, user-input, angular-directive, arabic, farsi

I have written an attribute directive to convert Persian and Arabic numbers to English numbers and I'm using it on many `<input>` tags all throughout my forms.

Problem is, sometimes it doesn't convert the last digits to English numbers. I mean, it shows the users that it does (conversion happens realtime because of the keyup event binding) but the information that gets sent to the server is wrong.

**Example:**

When I use this directive on an input, when the user enters `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` in the input field, I expect this directive to change it to `123456789` but it changes it to `12345678۹` or sometimes `123457۸۹`. (missing to convert the last digits)

**convert-to-english-numeral.directive.ts:**

```
export class Convert2EnglishNumeralDirective {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostListener('keyup') keyup() {
    const inputVal = this.elRef.nativeElement.value;
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.elRef.nativeElement,
      'value',
      `${convert2EnglishNumeral(inputVal)}`
    );
  }

  @HostListener('blur') blur() {
    const inputVal = this.elRef.nativeElement.value;
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.elRef.nativeElement,
      'value',
      `${convert2EnglishNumeral(inputVal)}`
    );
  }

  convert2EnglishNumeral(text: any): string {
    return text.toString().replace(/[\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]/g, (c) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-bitwise
      return c.charCodeAt(0) & 0xf;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this issue. I'm not sure if it's best practice or not but here it goes:

**convert-to-english-numeral.directive.ts:**

```
export class Convert2EnglishNumeralDirective {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostListener('keyup')
  onKeyup() {
    const inputVal = this.elRef.nativeElement.value;
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.elRef.nativeElement,
      'value',
      convert2EnglishNumeral(inputVal)
    );
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onInputChange(event) {
    const inputVal = this.elRef.nativeElement.value;
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.elRef.nativeElement,
      'value',
      convert2EnglishNumeral(inputVal)
    );
  }

  convert2EnglishNumeral(text: any): string {
    return text.toString().replace(/[\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]/g, (c) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-bitwise
      return c.charCodeAt(0) & 0xf;
    });
  }
}
```